# How to select and fill row in form

Tags: powershell, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I've powershell script which should basically fill the empty row in the picture. I'm not able to find solution on how to select that part and fill it with number. 
I've tried to find the name with regex but didn't succeed
here is part of the code

```
$krokPattern = "https://kazdykrokpomaha.ozp.cz/index.php?kroky/index"
$ie.navigate($krokPattern)

while($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }

[regex]$regex = "krok-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"
$stering = Select-String -Path $krokPattern -Pattern $regex
```

[Image - how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vf5dZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following with `-replace`. Just replace the value assigned to `$number` with whatever value you deem appropriate. However, a proper parser for the language in the file is going to be best.

```
$regex = [regex]'(?<=type=")[^"]+(?=" name="krok-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}")'
$number = 24
(Get-Content index.html) -replace $regex,$number | Set-Content index.html
```

**Explanation:**

Since `-replace` uses regex matching, we can build off of your current idea. See the following for the `$regex` breakdown. The goal is to match all characters between the double quotes after `type=` and before `name="krok-####-##-##"`.

- `(?<=)`: Positive Lookbehind
- `type="`: matches the characters type=" literally
- `[^"]+`: matches a single character that is not `"` one or more times (`+`).
- `(?=): Positive Lookahead
- `" name="krok-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"`: matches literally `"krok-` followed by 4 digits, a literal `-`, 2 digits, a literal `-`, 2 digits, and a final `"`.

The characters that match `$regex` are replaced by `$number`.

See [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ezL5YS/1) for example and deeper explanation.